# Intercepting a zoom URL with a Cypress Test

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

I have a test case that ends up redirecting to a zoom link. I'm trying to avoid the browser throwing up the "Open zoom.us" dialog box so I can conclude the test properly and verify that the browser did try to open the zoom link without it hanging the browser session and stopping JavaScript execution.

I'm currently trying to do this by using intercept, but it isn't working.

```
   it.only('Should login and click join zoom link successfully with a tester username and password', () => {
     LoginPage.login(credentials.tester.username, credentials.tester.password);

     cy.url().should('eq', `${Cypress.config().baseUrl}/myaccount`);

     cy.intercept({
        url: /^zoomus:\/.*/
     }).as('zoom')
     // Have also tried
     // cy.intercept(/^zoomus:\/.*/).as('zoom')

     MyAccount.clickFirstJoinViaZoomButton();

     cy.wait("@zoom")
  })

  export class MyAccount {
    static url = '/myaccount';

    static navigate() {
      cy.visit(MyAccount.url);
    }

    static clickFirstJoinViaZoomButton() {
      myaccountLocators.firstJoinViaZoomButton().click();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

It may be you have the commands in the wrong order, `cy.intercept()` is an event listener so it probably should be set before `.clickFirstJoinViaZoomButton()` fires the event.

Also, you have quotes around the regex expression, which means Cypress will not recognize it as a regex.

See [Matching URL](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Matching-url)

> // match any request that satisfies a regex pattern
>
> ```js
> cy.intercept(/\/users\?_limit=(3|5)$/)
> ```

Try this instead:

```js
cy.intercept(/^zoomus:\/.*/).as('zoom')

MyAccount.clickFirstJoinViaZoomButton()

cy.wait("@zoom")
```

Comment: Sadly neither of these changes made the difference - I still get the hard modal popup and the test fails. I've updated the question to reflect.

Comment: That is indeed sad - it means the presumption that the zoom link is using an HTTP request is incorrect. Please post the HTML around the link, it is likely to be javascript initiated.